# actualizar div o trozo de codigo php mysql cada cierto tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo un trozo de codigo, que hace muestra las mesas de un restaurant. Esto funciona de maravillas, pero lo que necesito es que este div, que contiene consultas intercaladas en trozos de codigo HTML, se actualice cada cierto tiempo, de manera que muestre las mesas que se han ocupado (por ventas), sin que el usuario este actualizando manualmente la pagina.
Adjunto imagen en donde se puede ver la visualizacion de las mesas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, los cuadros azules son las mesas desocupadas y los rojos las mesas que se ocuparon. Es esto lo que necesito, que me vaya mostrando en tiempo real, los cambios en las mesas, de manera que se pueda evitar el actualizar manualmente. 
Otro problema que tengo es que dentro de esta pantalla, se ejecuta un modal bootstrap y cuando hice las pruebas con un setinterval o settimeout, el modal simplemente desaparece cuando hace la actualizacion automatica.
Come mencione antes, esto es solo parte de un codigo mas extenso, pero lo que describo es lo que se muestra en la imagen. 
Aqui el codigo:

```
<div class="box-body">
<?php

foreach ($id_ub AS $ub_key){

$consulta = "SELECT id, nombre FROM ubicacion WHERE id_cl = '$id_cl' AND estado = 'S' AND id = '$ub_key'";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Last error: {$conexion->error}\n");
$id_u = array();
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
 while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
  $id_u[] = $row['id'];
?>

<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title"><b>MESAS <?=strtoupper($row['nombre'])?></b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
  <?php
  foreach ($id_u AS $ub_key1){

  $consulta = "SELECT id, num_mesa, tipo_venta, ubicacion, estado_pedido AS ocupada FROM mesas WHERE id_cl = '$id_cl' AND estado_gral = 'S' AND ubicacion = '$ub_key1'";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
      while ($qry = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
        if ($qry['ocupada'] == 'P') {?>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="small-box bg-red-gradient color-palette" style="height: 5rem;">
            <div class="inner" >
            <?php if ($qry['tipo_venta'] == 1){ //condicional de mesa ocupada?>
              <a href="pagar_ventas.php?mesa=<?=$qry["num_mesa"]?>&nom=<?=$qry["num_mesa"]?>&idub=<?=$qry["ubicacion"]?>&id=<?=$qry["id"]?>" style="color:white">
                <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"><?=$qry["num_mesa"]?></p>
              </a>
            <?php }else{ ?>
              <a href="pagar_ventas_ind.php?mesa=<?=$qry["num_mesa"]?>&nom=<?=$qry["num_mesa"]?>&idub=<?=$qry["ubicacion"]?>&id=<?=$qry["id"]?>" style="color:white">
                <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"><?=$qry["num_mesa"]?></p>
              </a>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php }else{ ?>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="small-box bg-blue color-palette" style="height: 5rem;">
              <div class="inner"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id3='<?=$qry["num_mesa"]?>' data-book-id='<?=$qry["id"]?>' data-book-id2='<?=$qry["ubicacion"]?>' data-target="#tipo-modal" style="color:white;">
                <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"><?=$qry["num_mesa"]?></p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } //fin condicional de mesa ocupada
      } //fin while mesas
    } //fin if mesas
  } //fin foreach mesas?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?  } //fin while ubicaciones
} //fin if ubicaciones
} //fin foreach ubicaciones?>

<div id="tipo-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">SELECCIONE TIPO DE VENTA.-</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="edit-content"></div>
 </div>
```

La idea es poder actualizar solo el estado de las mesas (cambio de color) de manera automatica sin afectar el funcionamiento general de esta parte, que es una de las mas criticas del sistema.

La consulta que hace el trabajo de ver los cambios en base de datos es:

```
$consulta = "SELECT id, num_mesa, tipo_venta, ubicacion, estado_pedido AS ocupada FROM mesas WHERE id_cl = '$id_cl' AND estado_gral = 'S' AND ubicacion = '$ub_key1'";
```

Agradezco como siempre cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme u orientacion de como poder realizar este proceso.

Comment: Amigo la mejor forma de actualizar datos sin querer recargar la pagina es mediante Ajax, pese a que son ventas, puedes hacer una funcion en Js que te envie un Ajax, te consulte la información y te la retorne actualizando asi solo las sillas a tu color correspondiente

Comment: @MaikerLeon estimado, gracias por responder. ya intente hacer lo que mencionas, pero el problema cuando hago eso, es que como tengo un modal inserto y que es parte fundamental tb del funcionamiento de las ventas, este desaparece al momento de hacer la actualizacion

Comment: no entendi totalmente lo que me dijiste, si me explicas mejor puedo quizas tarde mas ideas, que aunque no siempre son la solución pueden ser luz para la solución.

Comment: si claro. ese trozo de codigo, realiza la verificacion de mesas ocupadas o disp en BD. dentro de ese codigo, tengo una venta modal, que se abre cada vez que pinchas una mesa disponible y en ese modal, te pregunta que tipo de venta quieres hacer. el problema es que cuando hice una funcion en ajax que llama a un archivo en donde realizo la misma consulta, esta venta modal, al abrirla desaparece. ej: si quiero que ese div se refresque cada 3 seg, la ventana modal solo queda visible 3 seg y luego desaparece y es indispensable que ese modal este ahi, porque es fundamental para el funcionamiento.

Comment: Bueno en ese caso es dificil solo usar PHP debido a sus limitantes del lado del cliente, sin embargo si mezclas ambos es posible por ejemplo <script>
setInterval(function() {
    $("html").load("archivo.php");
},3000);
</script> si serapas el codigo y lo colocas aparte y le haces un include al inicio y luego esto quizas te funcione, claro es una idea

Comment: Por ejemplo en otro proyecto yo utilizo esto para calcular la hora por conteo en segundos function refrescar(){
 $("#search").load("post/consultar_datetime.php");
} entonces luego cada segundo mando a ejecutar en js esa function refrescar

Comment: @MaikerLeon intentare lo que me mencionas y te comento. gracias de antemano por tu orientacion

Comment: Tranquilo amigo estamos siempre para ayudar espero te funcione porque es la forma mas apropiada que veo para que realices lo que quieres exito.